# send results of DIR to text file

Tags: dos

I want to do a directory of a file and have the results go to a new text file which I can then edit. I used to do it all the time on DOS computers, and I have done it before with Windows, but I don't remember how and I have been searching "help" without getting anywhere.  I can get into "command line", but I cannot find how to direct the output to a text file, or run it as a batch file with the results to a text log.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ask about this?

```
dir > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't completely clear to me, but if you mean that you'd like to see a directory listing from the command prompt window, type:

`dir > output.txt`

or

`dir "C:\Program Files" > output.txt` (or any other full path)

The output of the `dir` command will be redirected to the file, `output.txt`. You can use the same syntax from within a batch file as well, if you like.